# How to turn CBUUID into string

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can't find any official way to get a UUID string back out of a CBUUID. These UUIDs can be 2 or 16 bytes long.

The goal is to store CBUUIDs in a file somewhere as a string, and then resurrect with [CBUUID UUIDWithString:] etc. Here is what I have so far.

```
// returns a simple 4 byte string for 16bit uuids, 128 bit uuids are in standard 8-4-4-4-12 format
// the resulting string can be passed into [CBUUID UUIDWithString:]
+(NSString*)CBUUIDToString:(CBUUID*)cbuuid;
{
    NSData* data = cbuuid.data;
    if ([data length] == 2)
    {
        const unsigned char *tokenBytes = [data bytes];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x", tokenBytes[0], tokenBytes[1]];
    }
    else if ([data length] == 16)
    {
        NSUUID* nsuuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:[data bytes]];
        return [nsuuid UUIDString];
    }

    return [cbuuid description]; // an error?
}
```

Comment: Apple just made all these answers obsolete with iOS 7.1. See my answer below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I rigged up the following category to do this for CBUUID:

```
@interface CBUUID (StringExtraction)

- (NSString *)representativeString;

@end

@implementation CBUUID (StringExtraction)

- (NSString *)representativeString;
{
    NSData *data = [self data];

    NSUInteger bytesToConvert = [data length];
    const unsigned char *uuidBytes = [data bytes];
    NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:16];

    for (NSUInteger currentByteIndex = 0; currentByteIndex < bytesToConvert; currentByteIndex++)
    {
        switch (currentByteIndex)
        {
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 9:[outputString appendFormat:@"%02x-", uuidBytes[currentByteIndex]]; break;
            default:[outputString appendFormat:@"%02x", uuidBytes[currentByteIndex]];
        }

    }

    return outputString;
}

@end
```

For this input:

```
NSLog(@"UUID string: %@", [[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0bd51666-e7cb-469b-8e4d-2742f1ba77cc"] representativeString]);
NSLog(@"UUID string2: %@", [[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1800"] representativeString]);
```

it produces the following output:

```
UUID string: 0bd51666-e7cb-469b-8e4d-2742f1ba77cc
UUID string2: 1800
```

and preserves the appropriate hyphenation for the 16 byte UUIDs, while supporting the simple 2-byte UUIDs.

Comment: Liked it. Its a little more complicated, but it does handle other lengths. But also the CBUUID is documented to be either 16 or 128 bit.

Comment: Worked perfect! I just copy and pasted it to just before @interface in my .m file, and viola!

Answer (score 8):

To all those saying that CBUUID is toll-free bridged with CFUUIDRef, it's not.

```
CBUUID * foo = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDCharacteristicExtendedPropertiesString];
CFStringRef fooBar = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, (__bridge CFUUIDRef)foo);
if (![CBUUIDCharacteristicExtendedPropertiesString isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)fooBar])
    NSLog(@"fubar!");
```

It's not crashing but you're getting garbage out. It's probably uniquely identifying garbage, but it can't be round-tripped.

PS: This didn't work as a comment because SO comments oddly don't allow code formatting.

Comment: not sure why this one was downvoted - Mark are you using a solution in the style of Brad's category?

Answer (score 7):

iOS 7.1 (beta released yesterday, 11/18/13) introduced the following property on `CBUUID`:

> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *UUIDString`
>
> *The UUID represented as a string. (read-only)*

From [CBUUID Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBUUID_Class/Reference/CBUUID.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBUUID/UUIDString).

It's also worth noting that for comparing a UUID string with a `CBUUID`, this works:

```
if ([cbuuidInQuestion isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1234-5678-9012-1234"]]) {
    // isEqual tests for "the same UUID"
    // == tests for "the same CBUUID object"
}
```

Comment: Anyone know if the UUIDString method is an undocumented method in 7.0?

Comment: UUIDString property has been gone from the document!

Comment: @TheFinestArtist, no it's not. It's simpy not yet merged into the public document. The link I included is a developer preview; you need an Apple Developer account to view. Or if you just want to take my word for it, `UUIDString` will be a property in the near future.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 7.0 instead of 7.1 you can get the string with `[[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:cbuuid.data.bytes] UUIDString]`.

Comment: I wanted to point this out- on MacOSX this is still difficult (10.9), @0xced's solution was really helpful for me

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been 7 month since it was asked and answered, but... `CBUUID` is “toll-free bridged” to `CFUUID` and the easiest way to convert is

```
 //CBUUID* uuid = descr.UUID;
 NSString* str = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid);
```

Comment: Does this work with CBUUIDs that are two bytes long? I don't see how, given that they are just structs.  They are not toll free bridged. CFUUIDs are simple structs, while CBUUID is an NSObject. There is a huge difference between them.

Comment: I am glad you figured it for yourself. For the rest of us it just works.

Comment: Can anyone point to where this is documented? Neither the CBUUID headers nor the Toll Free Bridging table in the Cocoa Fundamentals guide document this?

Comment: I think you'll find it's not toll-free bridged. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is swift extension of Brad Larson's answer :

```
import CoreBluetooth

extension CBUUID {

    func representativeString() -> String {
        let data = self.data

        let bytesToConvert = data.length
        let uuidBytes = UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(data.bytes)
        var outputString = String()

        for currentByteIndex in 0..<bytesToConvert {
            switch currentByteIndex {
            case 3,5,7,9:
                outputString += String(format: "%02x-",uuidBytes[currentByteIndex])
            default:
                outputString += String(format: "%02x",uuidBytes[currentByteIndex])
            }
        }

        return outputString
    }
}
```

From iOS 7.1 `UUIDString` property is there but for specific iOS7, above extension is good option.

Comment: This answer doesnt work anymore, data.bytes is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

There is native method in objective C and Swift and it is quite straight forward method.

```
NSString *str = characteristic.UUID.UUIDstring;
```

Same thing with Swift language 
Link to library-> 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid/1518742-uuidstring?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Swift makes it easy with the `uuidString` property of a CBUUID instance.

```swift
let x = "B5E4B1AA-A851-4148-BF91-03B9B342295C"
let x_uuid = CBUUID(string: x)        
print(x_uuid.uuidString)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid/1518742-uuidstring

Answer (score -1):

Brad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280278/3541063) does its work, but the solution could be simpler (though probably not more efficient) using `NSUUID` class:

```
// CBUUID+ToString.h

#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface CBUUID (ToString)

- (NSString *)toString;

@end

// CBUUID+ToString.m

#import "CBUUID+ToString.h"

@implementation CBUUID (ToString)

- (NSString *)toString {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(UUIDString)]) {
        return [self UUIDString]; // Available since iOS 7.1
    } else {
        return [[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:[[self data] bytes]] UUIDString]; // iOS 6.0+
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) also has `UUIDString` available

Comment: `initWithUUIDBytes:` expects eight bytes of data. In case of a 16 bit CBUUID this is undefined behavior.

Comment: "Instances of the CBUUID class represent the 128-bit universally unique identifiers," therefore the code is valid.

Answer (score -3):

The following Worked me without any error:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",  CFUUIDCreateString(nil, peripheral.UUID) ];
```

Comment: This works because peripheral UUIDs are NOT CBUUID. A CBUUID is not a CFUUID. It will blow up when handed a CBUUID.

Comment: Kindly check with reply of bioffe.