# How to get Bluetooth Device ID

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am developing an application which allow get information from bluetooth device (Smart Watch Heart ). I want to display list device like:

Device Name - Device ID
Device Name - Device ID
Device Name - Device ID

How can i do that ? What is the characteristic or services I should to subscribe ?

Comment: Is it with BlueTooth Low Energy? So, are you using `CoreBluetooth.framework` What have you tried? What's really your question? Temperature Sensor from Apple is a good start with BLE...

Comment: yes, i am using BLE. I only can get device name. could not get device ID.

Comment: Can get serial number or something like that?

Comment: `[aPeripheral UUID]`. Note that's is hashed with the iPhone ID, so you won't get the same UUID for the same device if you're using various iPhones.

Comment: how to parse it to string. when i parse it to CFStringRef i got 2A234-23n23.... something like that.

Comment: I just log them since they are kind of irrelevant for my own use... So I don't know... A way could by `[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@", [aPeripheral UUID]]`, but that's kind of ugly I think...

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275859/how-to-turn-cbuuid-into-string

Comment: I know there is an application can get device ID. But not sure that is real device ID or just generate from developer. MiCoach is display device ID like this format 000037A7, 0000362c

Comment: Try : NSString *UUIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, [peripheral UUID]);